# (British) Meaning of "in a jolly"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The north side, as political aficionados if not tourists will know, has the Treasury, appropriately forbidding.
>
> But the west? Somewhat incongruously, in a **jolly**, almost orangey brick, half of it houses the Royal Institution of Chartered Surveyors.

In this [quote](http://www.ft.com/intl/cms/s/2/1f8e8b22-a6f6-11e2-885b-00144feabdc0.html#slide7) of the end of the 1st and the start of the 2nd paragraph, **jolly** is a noun. Yet these two don't apply: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jolly#jolly-2 and

> (plural jollies) (UK) [a pleasure trip or excursion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jolly#Noun)?

Comment: The pleasure trip/excursion it is (almost) always _ **on** a jolly_, so the _in_ would rule that out (to a native speaker) immediately. Obviously that's not something that's easy to learn though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Jolly* here is an adjective modifying *brick*.

You are probably confused by the comma after *jolly*. There are two motives for that comma:

1. In English we separate successive adjectives modifying the same noun with commas in writing (and with 'comma intonation' in speech) to signify that they modify the noun separately rather than cumulatively. That is:

   - A *jolly orangey brick* is an orangey brick which is jolly, as distinguished from other orangey bricks which are not jolly.
   - A *jolly, orangey brick* is a brick which is both jolly and orangey; it allows the reader to understand that the jolliness is attributable to the orangeyness. That could not be the case in the version without the comma, which implies that there are orangey bricks which are not jolly.
2. The comma also helps the reader parse the phrase by separating *jolly* from *almost orangey*, thus making it a little clearer that *almost orangey* is a distinct adjective phrase.

The core phrase, leaving out the modifiers, is the preposition phrase *in brick*, which modifies the following clause *half of it houses*; *in brick*, said of  buildings, means that they are made of brick. Half of the south side of this street or block is buildings housing the RICS; these building are made of brick of an orangey color which gives the buildings a cheerful aspect.

Comment: There is another sense for, "a jolly orangey brick" (without the comma). It is rare now. 'The word, 'jolly' was at one time widely used in England  to mean 'very'. I was surprised to find this recent example, "This looks jolly interesting and useful." https://goo.gl/R1UliL, The meaning is, ""This looks very interesting and useful."  However I realise I have strayed off-topic. This meaning will not fit in the original because of the word 'almost' getting in the way.